# Given 2 outer points of a perfect circle, find the centerpoint

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Alright, I hope this makes some sense.

I am using a software that can create arcs.
This arc is defined by:
Begin point
End point
Center of "circle"

The center is supposed to be the center of the imaginary circle that these two points bind to.

Here is a bad picture:
[image]

I know p1 and p2. I know the circle is a perfect circle. I have no idea what the proper way to get the circle midpoint is!

Comment: The center can be any point on the line perpendicular to $P_1 P_2$ and passing through the center of that segment. You need a third point to define the circle.

Comment: @vonbrand Good point! So I find the intersection of p1 and p2, determine some arbitrary distance, then I have any center?

Comment: No, then you still have two choices for the centre.

Comment: No. The perpendicular to $P_1 P_2$ through the mid point between $P_1$ and $P_2$ defines the possible positions of the center.

Comment: You need an additional item of information. Acceptable choices are (1) a third point on the circle or (2) the angle p1-center-p2.